# Android - How to get merchant production keys for pay u

Tags: android, payu, payumoney

I am new in android and integrate payU money as payment gateway but not able to get success. I am using sample PayU demo from github and it runs fine. But as i changed

```
 String merchantProductionKeys[] = {"Sskq6q", "smsplus"};
```

merchant production key with my key, it start showing error - Mandatory params hash missing. And i donot know where to find merchant product keys.

```
String merchantTestKeys[] = {"OygoFs", "OygoFs"};
String merchantProductionKeys[] = {"Sskq6q", "smsplus"};
String merchantKey = env == PayuConstants.PRODUCTION_ENV ? merchantProductionKeys[merchantIndex] : merchantTestKeys[merchantIndex];
String mandatoryKeys[] = {PayuConstants.KEY, PayuConstants.AMOUNT, PayuConstants.PRODUCT_INFO, PayuConstants.FIRST_NAME, PayuConstants.EMAIL, PayuConstants.TXNID, PayuConstants.SURL, PayuConstants.FURL, PayuConstants.USER_CREDENTIALS, PayuConstants.UDF1, PayuConstants.UDF2, PayuConstants.UDF3, PayuConstants.UDF4, PayuConstants.UDF5, PayuConstants.ENV};
String mandatoryValues[] = {merchantKey, "10.0", "myproduct", "firstname", "me@itsmeonly.com", "" + System.currentTimeMillis(), "https://test.payu.in/_payment.php", "https://test.payu.in/_payment.php", merchantKey + ":payutest@payu.in", "udf1", "udf2", "udf3", "udf4", "udf5", "" + env};
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

In order to test the gateway using a test key and salt, kindly follow these steps:

1 - Go on test.payumoney.com
2 - Sign up as a merchant - use any of your valid email ids - kindly do not use a random email id.
3 - Complete the "Business Details" (You may use PAN no. ABCDE1234F and DOB - 01/04/1990)
4 - Complete "Bank Account Details" (You may use A/C no. - 1234567890 and IFSC- ALLA0212632)
5 - Go to below mentioned location to get the Test Merchant Id :
     Seller Dashboard -> Settings -> My account -> Profile Settings

Once you provide your test merchant id, we will approve it so that you can find your exclusive test key and salt at :
     Seller Dashboard -> Manage Account -> My account -> Merchant Key - Salt